# A Running problem

Tags: linear-algebra

So I am not getting any logic related to this :

> Usman, Bhushan and Shailu start running at the same time from the same point on a circular track of
>       70 meters radius. Usman and Bhushan run clockwise and Shailu runs counter clockwise. If Usman meets
>       Shailu every 66 seconds and Bhushan meets Shailu every 110 seconds, how frequently (in seconds) will
>       Usman meet Bhushan?

Now how can I calculate this?I tried out calculating the times for a round but speed is not given, any logic's?

Comment: This is almost certainly not a linear algebra problem.

Comment: @user47805 yeah..i was not sure about the tag..was searching for some "word problem" but doesn't exist.You are free to re-tag.

Comment: What does Shailu see every 660 seconds?

Comment: @User58220 sorry din't get you there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u,b,s$ denote the respective speeds in "rounds per second".
Then we are given that $u+s=\frac1{66}$ and $b+s=\frac1{110}$. We are asked to find $u-b$, or more precisely $\frac1{[u-b|}$.

We have 
$u-b = (u+s)-(b+s) = \frac1{66}-\frac1{110}$, hence
$$ \frac1{[u-b|} = \frac1{\frac1{66}-\frac1{110}}=165.$$

Comment: That's great! u+s=1/66 how you got these?

Comment: I mean how come 1/66? how 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Hand-waving solution:
From the point of view of Shailu, in 660 seconds one CW runner passes him/her 10 times, and the other CW runner passes him/her 6 times.  So the faster of those runners must pass the other 4 times in the 660 seconds, or every 165 seonds.

PS:  the radius is irrelevant...

Comment: That was cool..:D :)

Answer (score 0):

circumfrence or distance = 2. pi. r =440

time X speed  =440 --------------------------------------

66( u+s) = 440---------------------relative opposite direction

110(b+S) =440

u-b = 8/3 -----Speed ----relative speed same direction

8/3 X Time = 440

Time = 440 X 3/8

time=165

Comment: Use $\LaTeX{}{}$.